# Responsive embedded iframes that keep aspect-ratio ( the aspect ratios are variable)

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, responsive-design, sass

I need to embed an iframe in an element(at a certain position) and when I resize the window, I want the iframe to behave responsively, meaning when resized I need the aspect ratio to hold. I add the iframe over javascript.

The solution I have currently isn't sufficient because the container that I put this structure into should not have many nested divs because of stability reasons.

HTML:

```
<div class="large-container">
  <div style="width:500px;max-width:100%; background-color:blue;">
    <div class="aspect-ratio">
      <iframe width="500" height="285" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YFSSaLB-4SA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.large-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

.aspect-ratio {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 57%;
}

.aspect-ratio iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bo88ou0m/

The bottom-padding is what I can get from my code, finding the aspect ratio.

Does anyone have any links on articles on this that are newer. Some of the javascript solution's I have come across all had solutions on re-rendering(calling global functions) each time the DOM changes, adding an iframe. This isn't optimal because of scaling reasons.

Comment: can you try to also add right: 0 and bottom: 0 to your iframe's css?

Comment: You can make an [aspect ratio div using the padding-top technique](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/) and then absolutely position the iframe inside it (using left, top right and bottom:0;)

Comment: @Pete can you jsfiddle it on my example so I can see?

Comment: Changes have been made

Comment: Ah ok, you've used padding bottom instead of top - that is the only way to get your aspect ratio.  I don't see how nested divs causes instability

Comment: Because the component that it is in later gets changes and such